# Is it possible to get the browser's proxy server information?

Tags: javascript, proxy-server

I'm doing a research on how to get proxy server information of broswer(FF,chrome and IE) with javascript.

I've madesome research, but I'm confusing can I get proxy server information of broswer with javascript?

Comment: What does your research tell you thus far?

Comment: It's sure that set proxy-settings with javascript is impossible,but No results for my question:can I get proxy server information of broswer with javascript?